# NoneType object has no attribute GetOverviewCount

Tags: pyqt

Whenever I try to open a kea file in [TuiView](http://tuiview.org/), it throws me an error stating "NoneType object has no attribute GetOverviewCount".

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Can you add a little more info here? Are you on windows/mac/linux? Have you set the KEA driver path, as demonstrated in: https://spectraldifferences.wordpress.com/2014/05/27/arcsi/

Comment: I am in linux. Yes I have set the KEA driver path. 

export GDAL_DRIVER_PATH=~/miniconda3/lib/gdalplugins:$GDAL_DRIVER_PATH
export GDAL_DATA=~/miniconda3/share/gdal

Answer (score 1):

This error means that the file exists but GDAL can't open the image data, in the case of KEA files because it is being read as sub-datasets using the HDF5 driver rather than the KEA one.

As it looks like you are using conda I would recommend updating to the latest builds from conda-forge and installing in a separate environment using the following commands:

```
conda create -n tuiview_env -c conda-forge tuiview
source activate tuiview_env
```

The latest version of GDAL from conda-forge is built with KEA support so setting `GDAL_DRIVER_PATH` isn't required. A new environment is recommended because the `activate` script also sets other environmental variables used by GDAL (e.g., `GDAL_DATA`).

This will also work on Mac and Windows, although for Windows `source` isn't required when activating a new environment.